# Vim go to link in Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, vim

Is it possible to have a list of links in vim (seperated by newlines) and then use firefox to open these links?

I would have to externally call FF, but how would I pass what is under the vim cursor to the FF command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are several ways to do it. One way is by putting something like this is your `.vimrc`:

```
 nnoremap <leader>w :silent !xdg-open <C-R>=escape("<C-R><C-F>", "#?&;\|%")<CR><CR>
```

(Opens urls in default browser (via `xdg-open`) when you press <kbd>\</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>).
Check out the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_a_web-browser_with_the_URL_in_the_current_line) for more examples.

Another option would be to make your terminal emulator do that for you. But that depends on your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

For a robust solution that also includes the possibility to do various (Google etc.) searches from within Vim, check out the [openbrowser plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3133).